# Regex to extract title from webpage source

Tags: php, regex

Following regex works fine for me for most of url. But in case of few url, it does not give title, though source code has title.

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$title = get_title($data);
echo $title;
function get_title($html) 
    {
        return preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
    }
```

Here is the demo :   [DEMO](http://codepad.org/YDg1C0Kk)

Comment: i think that this question has been answered before here in SOF, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510124/regular-expression-to-get-page-title

Comment: just change your regex to the one mentioned in my answer

Comment: From your demo, it looks like the issue isn't with your regex, but is with getting the page contents in the first place via `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

```
<?php
 $url= 'http://www.indianic.com';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 
 //echo $result;  
$title = get_title($result);
 echo $title;
function get_title($html) 
{
            return preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
?>
```

Comment: no need of replacing file_get_contents to curl call, regex needs to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
 return preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/title>/ims', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
```

Checked and working

```
$url='http://www.ndtv.com/';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $data, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
    echo $title;
```

OUTPUT :- NDTV.com: India, Business, Bollywood, Cricket, Video and Breaking News

Comment: Reason for that is file_get_contents() not working for facebook, try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437688/loading-fb-thru-php-file-get-contents-throws-you-are-using-an-incompatible-we